# A certain generalization of flag varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, representation-theory

The most standard notion of a (partial) flag is the sequence of vector subspaces ordered by inclusion,
$$
V_1\subset V_2\subset \ldots \subset V_k=V.
$$
Given the dimensions of the subspaces $\dim V_i=d_i$, $d_k=n$, one can describe the variety of such flags by a quotient $G/P$ for $G=Gl_n$ and $P$ a parabolic subgroup.

The standard generalization of this notion is obtained by taking a more general $G$, and for algebraic groups there is a nice theory, which shows that the corresponding partial flag variety $G/P$ is projective and has much more say about it.

For the case of classical groups such as $SO_n$, the partial flag variety has a geometrical meaning as a space of approrpriately constrained flags in an inner product space $V$. No matter what is the explicit construction, the group $SO_n$ acts transitively on such flags.

What I want is a more general notion of a flag in inner product space. Consider, for example, a flag of the form
$$
V_1\subset V_2\subset V,
$$
where $\dim V_1=1, \dim V_2=2, \dim V=n$, and $V$ is an inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$ (i.e. equipped with non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form). I require of this flag that $(x,x)=0$ for any $x\in V_1$. Note that $SO_n$ does not act transitively on the space $F$ of such flags -- $V_2$ can be orthogonal to $V_1$, or it can be in generic position.

So $F$ cannot be possibly described as a quotient of $SO_n\mathbb{C}$. However, as far as I understand, almost all of $F$ is a single orbit of $SO_n \mathbb{C}$ -- I mean those flags when $V_2$ is in a generic position. So almost all of $F$ is of the form $SO_n\mathbb{C}/H$, for some subgroup $H$.

> Is there a standard algebraic-geometric approach to such spaces $F$, which will take into account the presence of $SO_n\mathbb{C}?$

Suppose I want to study a ring $R\subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle(x,x)\rangle$ of polynomials, related to this flag, defined by
$$
f(x,y+\alpha x)=f(x,y)\quad \mathrm{mod}\, (x,x),
$$
for $x, y\in V$, $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}$. Such polynomials can intuitively be considered as homogeneous functions on $V$.

> Can I describe the ring $R$ as some sort of coordinate ring for $F$ and possibly link it to representation theory on $SO_n\mathbb{C}$?

I am asking about representation theory here because I can describe $R$ by an ad-hoc calculation, and the representations of $SO_n\mathbb{C}$ play an important role in this description. I am also thinking about similar question for $SO_n\mathbb{C}/P$, when there is Borel-Weil theorem, etc.